# Elements of a localization

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> How does a localization at a prime look like, for example if we have $R:=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ and let the ideal $\mathfrak p:=\left(\sqrt{-3}\right)$ in $R$, what are the elements of $R_{\mathfrak p}$ ?

I have to find an easier expression than $\mathfrak pR$, for example $3\mathbb Z$ is contained in $\mathfrak p$, or otherwise is it superfluous to determine whether the localization is for example a local ring or a PID ?

Comment: In fact, R_p is the same as if you localize the Dedikind ring Z[(1+\sqrt{-3})/2] at (\sqrt{-3}), since 1+\sqrt{-3})/2 is a unit in R_p. Thus it's a discrete valuation ring. (This is analogous to localizing a singular curve at a smooth point.)

Comment: @JohnBrevik I think this is due to the fact that; The ring of integers $\mathcal{O} _K$ of a number field is always a Dedekind domain, right ? But how can you choose $\mathbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt{-13}}{2}]$, instead of $R$, If  $(1+\sqrt{-3})/2$ is a unit, then ?

Comment: The ring of integers of \Q(\sqrt{-3}) is [ℤ[1+√-3 / 2]. I didn't "choose" it :) And yes, that makes it a Dedekind domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]\subset\mathbb Z\left[\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right]\subset\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]_{(\sqrt{-3})}\subset\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-3}].$$ (For the second containment notice that $2\notin(\sqrt{-3})$.) If $z\in\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-3}]$ is integral over $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]_{(\sqrt{-3})}$, then there is $a\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]-(\sqrt{-3})$ such that $az$ is integral over $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$. Thus we get $az\in\mathbb Z\left[\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right]$, so $az\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]_{(\sqrt{-3})}$ which entails $z\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]_{(\sqrt{-3})}$.

This shows that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]_{(\sqrt{-3})}$ is integrally closed, so it is a DVR with $\sqrt{-3}$ as uniformizer.

Comment: Although It is an old question, but may I ask you how to find the uniformizer in last part?